# if condition in shell script for pushing files

Tags: shell, sh

I have tried to push a repo using the `sh` script , here i am not familiar with the script. so i have to throw alert a message, if the specified directory is not found into repo folder. But the code throws the message, even the folder found into the directory.

This is the code:

```
books=Digitalbooks/{bookdirectory}/{booktitle}

cd ${books}
# books
if [ ! -d "./OPS/components" ]; then
        echo "The components folder not found"
        read -p "Continue (y/n)?" CONT
        if [ "$CONT" = "n" ]; then
                exit
        else
                git status
                git add .
                git status
                git checkout origin {isbnno}/OPS/components/Digitalbooks/_framework
                git commit -m "Digitalbooks_{assignment}_{date}"
                sleep 2
                git pull origin master
                git status
                git push origin master
                git status
        fi
fi

# read
```

Please any one help to this.

Comment: please explain what the expected result is and how the actual result deviates.

Comment: @user803422, thanks for response. Actually i gave a repo path in a perl script, it will excute based on this `sh` script. i need to throw alert message, if the specified folder is missing into the given path, here used user prompt for continue the process or not that if no, execution will stop, else continue the execution.

Comment: Actually, the code reports the error only if the folder isn't there.  You can verify this easily if you put just before the `if` statement a `ls -ld ./OPS/components`.

Comment: @user1934428, thanks, however, that script doesn't work.

Comment: Is the text in braces a placeholder for actual text you don't wish to share, or do you have directory names containing literal braces, or are those supposed to be parameter expansions with the `$` missing?

Comment: The calls to `git status` are all unnecessary, as is likely the call to `sleep`.

Comment: Thanks to all, i resolved the issue, now it works fine after closing the 2nd if `if [ "$CONT" = "n" ]; then
                exit fi`.